# Fast-blow instead of slow-blow fuse in consumer hifi power supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer, fuses

I have a power supply unit for a hifi pre-amp. The power supply takes a slow-blow fuse (T2.5A/250V).

If I use a fast fuse (F2.5A/250V) instead, how likely is the fuse to blow during normal power-on?

Answer (score 2):

A slow blow fuse allows for inrush currents/startings currents that exceed 2.5A for a longer time. Your equipment probably needs that longer time, otherwise the developer of that power supply would have picked a fast blow fuse (because a fuse is intended to cut the power as fast as possible, so standard one would pick a fast blowing fuse).